# How can I use `if` in an adb run-as command?

Tags: android, adb

I want to check if there is a file in an Android app's private storage through adb, so I have to use `run-as <packagename>` in the command.

But it does not even let me use the `if` statement:

```
adb exec-out "run-as myPackage "if true; then echo HELLO; fi""
```

gives **`run-as: exec failed for if: Permission denied`**.

```
adb exec-out "if true; then echo HELLO; fi"
```

(without the `run-as`) gives: **`HELLO`**, as expected.

How can I use the `if` statement in a `run-as` command?

Answer (score 0):

`run-as` seems to be not smart enough to understand that whole block, it expects an executable.

```
adb -d exec-out run-as myPackage sh -c "if true; then echo HELLO; fi"
```

`sh` is smart enough.